# How can I modify object's attribute datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

Say I have this TYPE:

```
create or replace TYPE type1
AS OBJECT
  (order_date     DATE
  ,order_status   VARCHAR2(50)
  ,offer          NUMBER
)
```

How can I change datatype of 'offer' to `VARCHAR2(20)`?

Answer (score 1):

Only widening is possible with `ALTER TYPE` syntax:

```
ALTER TYPE type1 MODIFY ATTRIBUTE (offer  VARCHAR2(20));
-- only widening of attribute 'OFFER' constraints is allowed
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3fe9fe4f02e37d23fe6c1b89603aac8d)**

You need to recreate type:

```
create or replace TYPE type1 AS OBJECT(
   order_date     DATE
  ,order_status   VARCHAR2(50)
  ,offer          VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Comment: I think he wanna modify the 'offer' instead of 'order_status' field

Comment: @DiegoSouza Thanks, good catch. Still the same case: `only widening of attribute 'OFFER' constraints is allowed `

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to recreate a type *for your case*, only `DROP/ADD`(*with `cascade` or `invalidate` option*) an `ATTRIBUTE` is enough

```
ALTER TYPE type1 DROP ATTRIBUTE offer [cascade|invalidate];
ALTER TYPE type1 ADD ATTRIBUTE offer varchar2(20) [cascade|invalidate];
```